# AngularJS w/ Karma - loading Jasmine before Mocks

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner

Getting `module is not defined` when trying to run angularJS unit tests.

I've narrowed down the problem to following issue: Karma is loading angular-mocks.js before it's loading Jasmine, but [angular-mocks.js expects Jasmine to be there first](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.6/src/ngMock/angular-mocks.js#L1613).

How can I reorder my Karma file loads to ensure that Jasmine is loaded first?

Here's my karma config:

```
basePath = '../../../target';
frameworks = ['jasmine'];
files = [
    JASMINE,
    JASMINE_ADAPTER,
    'lib/angular.min.js',
    'lib/angular-mocks.js',
    'main/js/**/*.js',
    'test/js/**/*.js',
];
```

Versions:

- angular (and angular mocks) - 1.0.6
- karma - 0.8.5

Comment: Have you tried using `ANGULAR_SCENARIO` and `ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER`? In my `karma.conf.js` I load them in this order: `ANGULAR_SCENARIO, ANGULAR_SCENARIO_ADAPTER, 'http://code.angularjs.org/1.0.6/angular-mocks.js', 'test/scenarios/*.js'`.

Comment: I haven't, but understanding is that the SCENARIO dependencies are for end-to-end tests only (?).  I'm currently just unit testing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was due to a typo in my Karma config.  Apparently this is what happens..